# Does overloading ToString() prevent implicit comparison between numeric values?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, equality

I have an `Outer` class that contains a decimal field, called `Value`. It represents a value between 0 and 1 (inclusive) and contains a logical NOT `!` operator that subtracts its value from 1.

```
public class Outer : IEquatable<decimal> {
    public decimal Value;

    public Outer(decimal val = 0.5m) => Value = val;

    public override string ToString() => $"Value: {Value}";
    public bool Equals(Outer o) => this.Value == o.Value;

    public static implicit operator decimal(Outer o) => o.Value;
    public static implicit operator Outer(decimal d) => new Outer(d);

    public static Outer operator !(Outer o) => new Outer(1m - Value);
}
```

I am attempting to compare equality (implicitly) between `Outer a` and `Outer b` using their `Value` fields. If I initialize `a` with `0.75m`, `!a` should equal `0.25m`.

```
public class TESTING_Outer {
    [NUnit.Framework.Test]
    public void Not_Operator_Negates_Value() {
        Outer a = 0.75m, b = 0.25m;

        Assert.AreEqual(0.25m, !a);      // works with direct value
        Assert.AreEqual(b, (decimal)!a); // works with explicit cast

        Assert.AreEqual(b, !a);          // fails with implicit cast
    }
}
```

As the comments state, this test fails when attempting to check the equality of two `Outer` instances, despite them having the same value.

I get the following error output message:

```xml
Not_Operator_Negates_Value (0.045s)
---
  Expected: <Value: 0.25>
   But was: <Value: 0.25>
---
```

Why does the last `Assert` fail, and how do I make sure my objects are comparing their values correctly?

Comment: You need to override your object's `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. This has nothing to do with `ToString`. Because `Outer` is a class, checking whether two instances are equal means checking whether they're actually the same object instance (reference equality), rather than checking whether they semantically mean then same thing (value equality). Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to implement value equality. While you're at it, you'll probably want to override `==` and `!=` so that they work as expected. After all that your `Outer` should probably be a struct, not a class

Comment: _"// fails with implicit cast"_ - there is no cast taking place here because both objects are of the same type (`Outer`). It's not the same as the case above.

Comment: @canton7 oh I see

Comment: To be clear: I can see that you've defined an `Equals(Outer)` method, but that's just like any other method -- the runtime doesn't know anything about it, so it's not doing anything. You need to *overide* the `Equals(object)` method from `object`. If you want, you can also implement the `IEquatable<Outer>` interface, which will mean other things can know about your `Equals(Outer)` method -- but you must override `Equals(object)` either way. You must also implement `GetHashCode`, otherwise your type won't work as a dictionary key, or in a HashSet etc

Comment: I think I now know OP's confusion that also trapped me: The `ToString` is only used for the log display itself! It is not using `ToString` for doing the equality check itself... There you currently have - as @canton7 already explained - a **reference equals** check for the underlying `object` references due to the lack of according `IEquatable` implementation

Comment: (note the lack `IEquatable<T>` implementation isn't causing the problem directly -- this will be calling `object.Equals(object)`. The problem is that you haven't overridden that method. `IEquatable<T>` is something you can add on top of that: its main point is to avoid boxing value types when checking equality, which makes it arguably pointless for a class, but some people like to add it for clarity)

Comment: Thank you, everyone! It's funny because I actually stumbled upon all of these suggestions the hard way. My original class was implementing `IEquatable<decimal>`, which is why I had the `Equals(decimal)` method. I added the `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` methods and overloaded == and != before I realised my tests started passing because I commented out the "problem line", `Assert.AreEqual(b, !a)`. Funny how things work out.

Comment: Should I be implementing `IEquatable<Outer>` instead of `IEquatable<decimal>`? (And I assume the same would be true for `IComparable<T>` as well?)

Comment: @derHugo Yeah, I actually removed my `ToString()` method just to test that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually stumbled upon my mistake while writing the rest of my code. Turns out I just forgot a couple of overloads.

Thank you to everyone who commented on my question. You were all quick to point out exactly what I was missing! :)

```
public class Outer : IEquatable<decimal> {
    public decimal Value;

    public Outer(decimal val = 0.5m) => Value = val;

    public override string ToString() => $"Value: {Value}";
    public bool Equals(Outer o) => this.Value == o.Value;

    public static implicit operator decimal(Outer o) => o.Value;
    public static implicit operator Outer(decimal d) => new Outer(d);

    public static Outer operator !(Outer o) => new Outer(1m - Value);

    // What I needed to add:
    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj as Outer == null ? false : (obj as Outer).Value == Value;
    public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Should I be implementing `IEquatable<Outer>` instead of `IEquatable<decimal>`? What is the reason I would use one over the other?